# Java Generics method argument

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write an interface method, which will take an argument from a class which extends the common Payload.

```
public String buildRequest(<T> extends RestServicePayLoad payLoad);
```

purpose is so that any class that implements RestServicePayLoad can take an argument of that type and return a String.

Looks like my generics format is wrong. Please let me know what is the proper format.
Thanks!

Comment: nothing to tell :)

Comment: It is exactly the question: asking how to write a generic method. Doesn't matter whether it's in an interface or not.

Comment: @davidxxx He's asking for the syntax.

Comment: an instance of "any class that implements `RestServicePayLoad`" is just an instance of `RestServicePayLoad`. You just need to take `RestServicePayLoad`. No generics needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre very close

```
public <T extends RestServicePayLoad> String buildRequest(T payLoad);
```

Comment: How did you answer this after the question was closed? Bug?

Comment: @Gendarme I have no idea tbh. when I clicked submit that's when the duplicate banner appeared.

Comment: @Gendarme No bug (sadly), [there are no server side checks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible)...

Comment: Thanks anyway! for the answer and stack overflow link

Comment: but that's just equivalent to `public String buildRequest(RestServicePayLoad payLoad)` The generics is completely pointless here